# DynamoDB java filter list - example

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

My current schema is as follow:

- **userId**: hashKey
- **date**: range-key
- **label**: List of strings

I'm trying to run a query that gets items with hash-key, range-key and one or more specific label string. for example: user(123), since(1/13/2015), label (important,fun)

Based on my understanding, DynamoDB can give max of 2 indexes (global or local) so I need to use filters.

Running the following code works only when the labels are exactly the same, not one item in a list.

```
List <String>labels=new ArrayList<String>();
labels.add("fun");
labels.add("important");
Map<String,AttributeValue> expressionAttributeValues=new HashMap<>();
expressionAttributeValues.put(":pr", new AttributeValue().withSS(labels));
queryRequest.withFilterExpression("labels IN (:pr)");
queryRequest.withExpressionAttributeValues(expressionAttributeValues);
```

Can you give an example how to filter a list attribute (withSS)?

Comment: do you mean you want to query fun or important?

Comment: it's hard to understand from your question what works and what doesn't

Comment: Yes, i would like to query a specific user, from specific date with specific labels (can be fun, can be important or can be both).

Comment: this example works only in case the filter matches exactly the array of labels. For example: if the record has label "fun" and the query label is "fun" then the record returns. In case the record has "important,fun" (its a List) and i query for fun, then the record does not return

Answer (score 4):

Please try with the below syntax. It works for me.

```
expressionAttributeValues.put(":pr", new AttributeValue().withSS(labels));
queryRequest.withFilterExpression("contains(labels, :pr"));
```

Comment: withS is not accepting List. Any other alternative way to do this ?

Comment: @Harish it is `withSS` ,adding one more S in the end

Answer (score -1):

If you still haven't found a solution, one more suggestion. Pass the `List<String>` as comma-separated String values inside IN Clause, that will work.

Comment: Have you tested yet?

Comment: This does work but vulnerable to query injection.