# Dynamodb - Scan and filter data from numeric list without including key attribute in the filter criteria

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am trying to filter the data from numeric list. I have used Scan with filter by list (i.e. withNS). I have followed the solution in below post. I am neither getting any error nor getting the values in the result set.

[DynamoDB java filter list - example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929156/dynamodb-java-filter-list-example)

```
DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression()
            .withFilterExpression("Comments.UserIds IN (:val1)")
            .withExpressionAttributeValues(eav);
```

Comments is a complex object which has List userIds (type : Integer). I would like to filter the data by userIds. I don't have all the userIds. If the list contains five user ids, I would have one or two user ids.

Is there a way to achieve this requirement in AWS SDK - Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keywords "contains" solved the problem. Now, I am able to filter the data by few values present in the list.

```
eav.put(":val1", new AttributeValue().withN(userId));
DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression()
        .withFilterExpression("contains (Comments.UserIds, :val1)")
        .withExpressionAttributeValues(eav);
```